# How to change the status bar color when opening MFSideMenu

Tags: ios7, statusbar, xcode5, uistatusbar

When I open the MFSideMenu the status bar doesnt change color to black and the text color to white in iOS7. I have set UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance to YES and NO and both dont change the status bar color.

[image]

Comment: Check out this [solution][1]
I think it will help.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19010500/ios7-side-menu-status-bar-color-transition-as-in-the-ios7-facebook-app

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem. I did a little workaround by adding 20px light gray view at the top of right view controller. 
It is not a solution but looks better.

Comment: This is an old answer. From what i remember you can just added this view trough interface builder. Now i think there are some better libraries eg: ECSlidingViewController or RESideMenu.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out code at:
https://github.com/ryuichisaito6/MFSideMenu/commit/50bc3c1a5eec0dfb3c97621dd0f43f6e0ac70a20
"Darken status bar background color when side menu opens"